# Google sheets document has no owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am owner of a very old shared google sheet. Today I wanted to deploy some apps script and I got the message that I need to be in the same domain as the owner to deploy the script.

When I open the sheet and check sharing settings there are only editors. Nobody is owner of the document. There are 2 members and both are my accounts. One is my workspace account. The other is my private account. Both are editor.

Could this have something to do with the company owning the my google workspace account changing recently?

Help :)

Edit: Even weirder, I made a copy of the document from my google workspace account. I am only editor on the copy..(!?) But...I am able to publish web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the reason for this, partly. I don't know why there is no owner but for some reason when I open the apps script from the spreadsheet logged into my workspace account the screen opens up with my private account logged in. Once I changed the logged in account on the apps script screen, I was able to publish Apps Script Apps.